# How to Proxy, Remoting, HttpTunnel, through IIS

Tags: iis, proxy, tunnel, .net-remoting, http-tunneling

I'm not sure of the best solution to this problem. The current network is setup as:

Web server => Cms server => DB server

This is an existing setup for security reasons and cannot change. The Web server is connected to the internet, and can connect to the Cms server but not the DB server. The Cms server can access the DB server. (The idea was if the Web server got hacked, they would have to get past the Cms Server before getting to the DB server)

My current implementation to the problem as to create a simple proxy on the Web server, with the website on the Cms server (as the website need to access the DB). This works ok but i have timeout issues randomly. I've written the proxy in MVC and its very simple and works. Is this the best solution or is there a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this is a simple IIS setting under Application Request Routing, enable Proxy: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing